# Solution to simple linear 2nd order partial differential equation with boundary conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, linear-pde

I am trying to find out the form for solutions to this equation:

$\partial_x^2u(x,M) = 0$, where x and M are not independent (M is the running maximum of process x, but I don't think that's necessary for this question I am asking)

So I am trying to find an equation for $u(x,M)$ and was doing this by integrating twice. I am unsure if I am doing this correctly, and wanted some help checking the steps.

---

$\int \partial_x^2u(x,M)dx = \int0 dx$
$ \partial_xu(x,M) + g(M) = f(M)$

then I combine the functions $g$ and $f$ together to just $g$ since they are arbitrary

$\partial_xu(x,M) + g(M) = 0$

then integrate again:

$\int \partial_xu(x,M)dx + \int g(M)dx = \int0dx$
$u(x,M) + j(M) + g(M)(x + k(M)) = l(M)$

So here to calculate $\int g(M)dx$ I am unsure if we can hold $g(M)$ constant since $M$ is a function of $x$, but since the partial derivative would keep $M$ fixed, I assumed it was and calculated $g(M) * \int1dx = g(M) * (x + k(M))$

So the final solution seems to be (combining $j$ and $l$ to $j$):

$u(x,M) + j(M) + g(M)(x + k(M)) = 0$
$u(x,M) + j(M) + g(M)x + g(M)k(M) = 0$

Can this be further simplified? Is $g(M)k(M)$ able to be made into some other function $r(M)$ or is it supposed to be kept separate?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from a bit of research/textbooks that the general form for the solution here is $u(x,M) = a(M)x + b(M)$, which confirms the process used above.

Since $g(M)k(M)$ is just a function of $M$, then it can be written as $r(M)$ and then you can add it to $j(M)$ to get the new function $-b(M)$. Then rewrite $g(M)$ as $-a(M)$, and then we get the form $u(x,M) = a(M)x + b(M)$.

Using the negative sign in front of the functions can be done since the functions are just arbitrary.